# What does "The code generator has deoptimised the styling of [some file] as it exceeds the max of "100KB"" mean?

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I added a new npm package to my project and require it in one of my modules.

Now I get this message from webpack,

`build modulesNote: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "D:/path/to/project/node_modules/ramda/dist/ramda.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".`

What does it mean? Do I need to take some action?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

This is related to `compact` option of Babel compiler, which commands to *"not include superfluous whitespace characters and line terminators. When set to 'auto' compact is set to true on input sizes of >100KB."* By default its value is "auto", so that is probably the reason you are getting the warning message. See [Babel documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/).

You can change this option from Webpack using a [query parameter](http://webpack.github.io/docs/using-loaders.html#query-parameters). For example:

```
loaders: [
    { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel', query: {compact: false} }
]
```

Comment: And if you have multiple loaders, you can use `?compact=false` instead of the `query` parameter. For example:
`{test: /\.js$/, loaders: ['ng-annotate', 'babel?compact=false']}`

Comment: @Ricardo Stuven but why would i change it to false? seems like a positive thing to "not include superfluous whitespace characters and line terminators"

Comment: @omriman12 It depends on how you're going to use the output. If it's a production build which is going to be minified, then there's no value in setting this parameter to `false`. For cases like mine where the format of the output is important, that has value. Like most things, it depends. :)

Comment: Does compaction effect performance?

Answer (score 57):

This seems to be a [Babel error](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/v5.1.11/src/babel/messages.js#L22). I'm guessing you use babel-loader, and are not excluding external libraries from your loader test. As far as I can tell, the message is not harmful, but you should still do something like this:

```
loaders: [
    { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel' }
]
```

Have a look. Was that it?

Comment: Weird, I see same message (also for ramda), although I do `exclude: /node_modules/`.

Comment: Same path, also? Maybe your external library is located elsewhere? If not, you could also try Ricardo's solution. This problem is not very critical.

Comment: My bad. I was checking wrong config. The actual one didn't have `exclude`.

Comment: I found this answer better. Thanks @mhelvens

Comment: It works,so we should exlude /node_modules/, i exclude also /dist/ for any case.Upvoted.

Answer (score 28):

Either one of the below three options gets rid of the message (but for different reasons and with different side-effects I suppose):

1. exclude the `node_modules` directory or explicitly `include` the directory where your app resides (which presumably does not contain files in excess of 100KB)
2. set the [Babel option](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/) `compact` to `true` (actually any value other than "auto")
3. set the Babel option `compact` to `false` (see above)

#1 in the above list can be achieved by either excluding the `node_modules` directory or be explicitly including the directory where your app resides.

E.g. in `webpack.config.js`:

```
let path = require('path');
....
module: {
     loaders: [
          ...
          loader: 'babel',
          exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/')
```

... or by using `include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/')` (again in `webpack.config.js`).

#2 and #3 in the above list can be accomplished by the method suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29857361/274677) or (my preference) by editing the `.babelrc` file. E.g.:

```
$ cat .babelrc 
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
    "compact" : true
}
```

Tested with the following setup:

```
$ npm ls --depth 0 | grep babel
├── babel-core@6.7.4
├── babel-loader@6.2.4
├── babel-preset-es2015@6.6.0
├── babel-preset-react@6.5.0
```

Answer (score 13):

I tried Ricardo Stuven's way but it didn't work for me. What worked in the end was adding "compact": false to my .babelrc file:

```
{
    "compact": false,
    "presets": ["latest", "react", "stage-0"]
}
```

Comment: Using babel 6.5.x, webpack 2, I had the same message but for `lodash.js`,   and this fixed the issue.

Comment: Came looking for this :)

Comment: Thanks, I had the exact same thing

Answer (score 6):

For more explanation read [**Babel Options - `compact`**](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/options#compact), it is option of `Babel compiler` that commands to *not include superfluous whitespace characters and line terminators.* some times ago its threshold was `100KB` but now is `500KB`.

I proffer you disable this option in your development environment, with this code in `.babelrc` file.

```
{
    "env": {
      "development" : {
        "compact": false
      }
    }
}
```

For production environment `Babel` use the default config which is `auto`.

Answer (score 4):

For those who's working with latest `webpack` and has `options` property on there configuration. You cannot use `query` and `options` at the same time. You will get this error if both is present

```
Error: Provided options and query in use
```

Instead, add new property to `options` name [`generatorOpts`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#generatoropts), then add the property [`compact`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#compact) under it.

```
loaders: [
   { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel', option: { generatorOpts: { compact: false } } }
]
```

And for those who's working with `next` (like me). You need to do something like this

```
config.module.rules.filter((rule) => rule.use && rule.use.loader === 'next-babel-loader')
.map((loader) => {
    loader.use.options.generatorOpts = { compact: false };
    return loader;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In react/redux/webpack/babel build fixed this error by removing script tag type text/babel

got error:

```
<script type="text/babel" src="/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

no error:

```
<script src="/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is maybe not the case of original OP question, but: if you exceeds the default max size, this maybe a symptom of some other issue you have. in my case, I had the warrning, but finally it turned into a FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: semi-space copy, fallback in old gen Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory.
the reason was that i dynamically imported the **current** module, so this ended up with an endless loop...

Comment: It was a symptom for me - I started removing/adding my imports to try and track it down. The offending script was using a dynamic require(`require('../../../' + a + '/' + b)`). Removing it solved the issue (and it shall never return).

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, this was exactly my issue. Thanks shmuel!

Answer (score 1):

in webpack 4 with multiple module rules you would just do something like this in your .js rule:

```
{
     test: /\.(js)$/,
     loader: 'babel-loader',
     options: {
          presets: ['es2015'],    // or whatever
          plugins: [require('babel-plugin-transform-class-properties')], // or whatever
          compact: true    // or false during development
     }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my babel configuration:

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [['@babel/preset-env'], ['@babel/preset-react']],
  plugins: [
    [
      '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
      {
        corejs: 3,
      },
    ],
    // react hmr
    ['react-refresh/babel'],
  ],
};
```

I also met this problem because these code:

```js
    [
      '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
      {
        corejs: 3,
      },
    ],
```

And finally I solved this problem by add

```
exclude: /node_modules/
```

in

```
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
      },
```

Comment: same error, and  exclude: /node_modules/ fix the problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with video.js, Adding that specific package fixed the issue for me.

```
exclude: devMode ? /node_modules/ : [
/node_modules\/video.js/, /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime|core-js/],
```

Answer (score 0):

It indicates that your code generator (likely a JavaScript bundler like Webpack or a JavaScript minifier) has encountered a large amount of styling information, and it has deoptimized or altered the way it's handling this information due to its size.

To solve it, Minify your CSS code to reduce its size. You can use a tool like cssnano to automatically minify your CSS.

```
npm install cssnano --save-dev
```

Then, use it in your build process, for example, with Webpack:

```
const cssnano = require('cssnano');

module.exports = {
  // ... other webpack config settings
  plugins: [
    // ... other plugins
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({
      cssProcessor: cssnano,
      cssProcessorPluginOptions: {
        preset: ['default', { discardComments: { removeAll: true } }],
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```