# grunt babel 100 kb styling issue

Tags: gruntjs, babeljs

When i am running [grunt babel](https://github.com/babel/grunt-babel) task, its keep giving me

Note :

> Running "babel:dist" (babel) task
>   [BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "common.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".
>   [BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "detailjs" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".

Could someone please tell me why this happens and what is the fix for this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug in your code. Babel is reporting that the files `common.js` and `detailjs` are greater than 100 KB in size, which means that Babel will not try to generate "pretty" code output. The `compact` option changes this behavior, and has three valid values: `auto`, the default, which disables pretty generation of files greater than 100 KB in size; `true`, which always disables pretty generation; and `false` which always generates pretty code.

You can pass the `compact` option to Babel with a value of `true` to prevent the message you are seeing from appearing, however this will also prevent Babel from generating pretty output.

If you want pretty output, at the penalty of performance, and want to prevent the warning you are seeing, you can set `compact` to `false`, which will always generate pretty code.

Note that while Babel considers this code "pretty", it may not satisfy your ideals of beautiful code.