# Syntax error in rarwe/bower_components/jquery/src/intro.js: Unexpected token (45:0)

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-cli, babeljs

I've been following the Rock-and-Roll with Ember.js tutorial. I'm doing it in an Arch virtual machine.

When I do `ember serve`, I get:

```
SyntaxError: rarwe/bower_components/jquery/src/intro.js: Unexpected token (45:0)
  43 | // you try to trace through "use strict" call chains. (#13335)
  44 | //"use strict";
> 45 | 
     | ^
    at Parser.pp.raise (/home/ran/r-and-r/rarwe/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/location.js:24:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/home/ran/r-and-r/rarwe/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/util.js:82:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (/home/ran/r-and-r/rarwe/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:425:12)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/home/ran/r-and-r/rarwe/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:236:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/home/ran/r-and-r/rarwe/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:217:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/home/ran/r-and-r/rarwe/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:163:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (/home/ran/r-and-r/rarwe/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:145:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (/home/ran/r-and-r/rarwe/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:112:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExpression (/home/ran/r-and-r/rarwe/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:79:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseStatement (/home/ran/r-and-r/rarwe/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/statement.js:137:23)
```

After Googling, I see at least one other person has experienced the same error, but nobody explains it.

Comment: The `generator has deoptimised` message is not an error and is unrelated to your syntax error. That's just a message you get if you `require` a large file.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Cheers. Is it normal?

Comment: @NaN Here's my answer related to the `generator has deoptimised` error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690481/grunt-babel-100-kb-styling-issue/31736448#31736448

Comment: @NaN Can you provide a more minimal test case example? When I do `bower install jquery`, the file that Babel seems to be trying to transpile is just a header for jQuery files, and is not valid JavaScript. We need more information regarding the setup you have in order to diagnose the problem further.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a bower_components directory inside your app directory. bower_components should only be on the root.

```
> Remove the bower_components directory
> Remove the tmp directory on root
```

This will do the trick