# Webpack slows down page

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have the following config for my webpack:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var config = {

  entry: {
    login: path.join(__dirname, 'src' , 'entry' , 'login.js'),
    register: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'entry', 'register'),
    faqLogged: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'entry', 'faqLogged'),
    content: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'entry', 'content'),
  },

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },


  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
}
module.exports = config;
```

In my app I use AJAX and I ought use babel-loader. The problem is, if I use the cdnjs for babel-loader, and therefore no `import` statements in my app, the page loads almost instantly.
On the other hand, if I use webpack to bundle my page, now being able to use `import`, and doing so, will result in my page load time being over 4 seconds and I receive the following error in my browser's console ( Chrome ) :

`[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "http://localhost/build/content.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".`

I have tried to minify the bundled file but that does not seem to be the issue. The fact that it has over 100kb doesn't bother me, what does is the absurd load time.

Comment: Can you share your full webpack config?

Comment: I have updated the question with my full webpack config.

Comment: Can you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576341/what-does-the-code-generator-has-deoptimised-the-styling-of-some-file-as-it-e? Be good to rule that out - if it fixes we can close as a duplicate.

Comment: I have tried that about 3 hours ago. Didn't affect the load time.

Comment: Why so many entry points? Is there not a root component that is the main entry?

Comment: Those are different bundles for different pages. That unfortunately isn t the issue here lux.

Comment: The problem was I wasn't using import $ from 'jquery' . I don t know why the script was working though.